# Query to return (grouped) rows where no row with column=condition exists

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table with two columns, a client_id and a boolean.

There are multiple data entries for a given client_id, each of which may or may not have the boolean value set to true.

I need a query that will return only the client_ids that have NO ROWS with the boolean set to true, and I need it grouped by client_id.

I'm sure this is simple, it just escapes me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` clause to filter the groups:

```
SELECT client_id FROM my_table GROUP BY client_id HAVING SUM(boolean) = 0
```

Note that `SUM(boolean)` works in MySQL because it does not have true boolean types; in other RDBMS you would either have to use a different aggregate function or else test the boolean and return a result that can be used in `SUM()`:

```
... HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN boolean THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: ok thanks, only my boolean is not really a boolean, it's more of a flag, in fact it's a CHAR which is either '' or 'on'.

Comment: @Keith: Then you can further abuse MySQL's lack of real boolean types with the rather succinct `... HAVING SUM(boolean='on') = 0`.

Comment: so is HAVING COUNT(boolean!='on')=0 correct? (I was typing this, while you posted the above)

Comment: @Keith: No.  `COUNT()` returns the number of non-`NULL` values in the group; in your case, `boolean` is always non-`NULL`.  Use `SUM()` as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: OK, I have to work this into the right side of a join now, but you answered the question, thanks!

Comment: Another thing, what if boolean could be NULL, '' or 'on', which is actually the case, I have discovered. I know I could redefine the column as NOT NULL, but is there a way without doing that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22600/discussion-between-keith-and-eggyal)